# How can I make a get_data() function?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a struct with a union inside. How can I make a `get_data()` function that should return a `bool` if(value == input_value::_bool).

```
enum class input_value {
    _bool,
    _1D,
    _2D,
    _3D,
};

struct input_action {

    union input_action_data {
        bool boolean;
        f32 _1D;
        glm::vec2 _2D;
        glm::vec3 _3D{};
    };

    input_value value;
    input_action_data data;

}
```

A template like this is not working:

```
template <typename T>
data get_data() const {

    static_assert(std::is_same<T, bool>::value || std::is_same<T, f32>::value || std::is_same<T, glm::vec2>::value,
        "Unsupported data type");

    switch (value) {
    case PFF::input_value::_bool:
        return data.boolean;

    case PFF::input_value::_1D:
        return data._1d;

    case PFF::input_value::_2D:
        return data._2d;

    case PFF::input_value::_3D:
        return data._3d;

    default:
        return T{};
    }
}
```

I do not want this:

```
example_input_action->get_data<bool>()
example_input_action->get_data_bool()
```

Comment: A  side note: it's not a good idea to have identifier names starting with `_` - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier.

Comment: Templates have to be resolved at **compile time**, so you can't have different return types inside the *same* templated function. You can look at [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) as a replacement for your `union` but, even then, you'll need to process the `index()` value and use `std::get<T>(x)` in run-time `switch` blocks, or some such.

Comment: Note, also, that function overloads won't really help, because your desired `get_data()` function would differ *only* in its return type ... and that ain't allowed, either.

Comment: *”Templates have to be resolved at compile time, so you can't have different return types inside the same templated function.”* @AdrianMole my answer seems to suggest otherwise. You can implicitly convert.

Comment: "I do not want this:" What *do* you want? Show a usage example.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon No, your answer does not suggest anything remotely close. You propose to add an implicit conversion from `bool` to `input_action_data`, but it won't help when you have `input_action_data` and you want `bool` as OP indicates.

Comment: *function that should return a bool if(value == input_value::_bool).* A function cannot decide which type to return based on a run-time value.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI but I modified the OP’s already existing code. While OP says return a `bool`, OP is actually returning a `union` in code. I worked off what was already in code. The wording could be a typo.

Comment: your'e trying to implement `std::variant` which isn't implementable within issued ISO standards

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon The question is very clear "How can I make a get_data() function that should return a bool if(value == input_value::_bool).". OP's code is invalid and doesn't do what OP needs to do, because it's hard and might even be impossible, and OP doesn't know how to do that. Your code doesn't do that either, because (surprise!) it's hard or impossible and you don't know know how to do that. So you decide that what OP is asking must be a typo, and write valid code that does *something*. Anybody can write valid code that does something. This is not what the question is about.

Comment: *"OP's code is invalid and doesn't do what OP needs to do"*. @n.m.couldbeanAI fair enough.

Comment: One way would be to have a function that returns a `std::any` type - but that would effectively achieve nothing, because you would still need to add code to resolve what type it holds at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

A function cannot return multiple types in C++.

| Returned object | *Type* |
| --- | --- |
| `data.boolean` | `bool` |
| `data._1d` | `f32` |
| `data._2d` | `glm::vec2` |
| `data._3d` | `glm::vec3` |
| `T{}` | `template parameter` |

<sub>*These are the types returned conditionally in the switch statement.*</sub>

*Secondly*, `data` is a member variable not a type so change the function signature.

---

Even if you change the function signature to:

```
template <typename T>
input_action_data get_data() const;
```

This line will not allow the code to compile:

```
default:
    return T{};
}
```

Because `T` is not a member of the returned `union`.

*Aside: I will suggest code review and redesign.*

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

Consider the following small snippet:

```
input_action foo = (std::rand()%1) ? input_action(true) : input_action (2.0f);
auto bar = foo.get_data();
```

The type of `bar` has to be determined at compile time, but `std::rand()` hasn't run yet. That will only execute at runtime.

Comment: It is odd how everyone here seems to agree that we should follow OP’s wording over OP’s attempt in code. What say you @MSalters?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon: There is no code showing what OP wants. There are only two lines of code demonstrating what the OP does _not_ want. (`get_data<bool>` and `get_data_bool`).

Comment: The question is indeed broken.